# Issue with YouTube implementation using Google API

Tags: youtube

Hi iam trying to access YouTube data API by OAuth 2.0 authentication.I obtained access token and refresh token successfully.Now i am trying to upload video by using the following link .

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#upload_a_video
```

I am unable to create credentials.pls suggest me the what is the userid i need to pass and from where i can get the userid to authorize method.

```
Credential credential = Auth.authorize(scopes, "uploadvideo");
```

Comment: what programming language ?

Comment: With OAuth2 you have to pass the "access_token" you have received after login credentials validated.

Comment: the programming language i am using is java @яша

Comment: dear ji_bay_         i know i have to pass the access token to get the user details.can u please share me how to get the user details and along with that post a video to the login client's channel